# Set height of all ul tags on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change all `ul` tags height to auto on click

```
<div class="hey">Click me</div>
<ul style="height:100px">My Height</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.hey').click(function(){
            $(this).next().find('ul').css('height','auto');
        });
    });
```

Did I miss anything?

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/376/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to find all the next sibling elements

```
$(this).nextAll('ul').css('height', 'auto');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zV5Sb/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hey').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('ul').css('height', 'auto');
    });
});
```

This approach will work for the case if your div has previous `ul` siblings as well.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/379/)**